# Calculate the limit of $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{e}}{x}\right)$

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I have to calcuate this limit: $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\frac{\left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}{e}}{x}\right)$$

I have no idea how to start, maybe taylor series?

Thanks.

Comment: Taylor series would work. You need to know that of $\ln(1+x)$ and $e^x$ around $0$: start with what is inside the parenthesis, remembering that $(1+x)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)}$. Expansion to order 2 should be enough, at first glance.

Comment: I have tried without success.
Can you help me ?

Comment: See below. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Detailed approach, using Taylor series. You will need the following two expansions (to order 2 and 1):
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x-\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2) \\
e^x &= 1+x + o(x)
\end{align}
$$
around $0$.

Now, starting from inside the parenthesis and working our way to the full expression:
$$
\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x) = 1-\frac{x}{2} + o(x)
$$
so
$$(1+x)^{1/x} = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)} = e^{1-\frac{x}{2} + o(x)} = e\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2} + o(x)} = e(1-\frac{x}{2}+ o(x))$$
and
$$
1-\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} }{e} = 1 - (1-\frac{x}{2}+ o(x)) = \frac{x}{2}+ o(x).
$$
Plugging it back for the coup de grâce, you get
$$
\frac{1-\frac{(1+x)^{1/x} }{e}}{x} = \frac{1}{2}+ o(1) \xrightarrow[x\to0]{} \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Substitute $y=\frac{1}{x}$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{y \to \infty}y\left(1-\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{y} \right)^y}{e} \right)
$$
now use the series expansion at $\infty$
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y=e-\frac{e}{2y} + O \left(\frac{1}{y^2}\right)
$$
and you have the result .